# Problem with displaying content made with WYSIWYG in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates, wysiwyg, django-wysiwyg

In one of my projects there was need to implement WYSIWYG-editor into django admin. I've installed http://code.google.com/p/django-tinymce/. Everything works well, but there is a problem with rendering the content made with WYSIWYG-editor. As a result, on html page returns special chars instead of normal html-tags and I see "plain" html tags with no html-layout.

Maybe the problem is in the templates? I simply output variable like `{{ content }}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try `{{ content|safe }}`

> Marks a string as not requiring
>   further HTML escaping prior to output.

via [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#safe)